# onmouseover and jquery function not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
"<a " . $thumbs . " href=\"" . $url . "\" class=\"download\" rel=\"files/" . $dir . "/" . $file . "\" title=\"" . $alt . "\"   ".$hover." > </a>"
```

when mouse is hovered on that link, a function is called:

```
$hover = " onmouseover=\"showImageThumbnail(this, '".$url_thumb."')\"";
```

the function itself:

```
function showImageThumbnail(obj, url){          
    xOffset = 30;
    yOffset = 10;

    $.get(url, function(data) {
        $(obj).hover(function(e){

            $("body").append("<p id='screenshot'><img src='data:image/jpg;base64,"+ data +"' alt='Atsisiųsti' /></p>");                              
            $("#screenshot")
            .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
            .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
            .fadeIn("fast");                        
        },
        function(){ 
            $("#screenshot").remove();
        }); 
        $(obj).mousemove(function(e){
            $("#screenshot")
            .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
            .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
        });
    });
}
```

My problem is that my function is not working correctly, I need to hover twice to make it working. This function is like tooltip, it shows image thumbnail. I think, I need to remove `.hover.` method, but after that my function not working at all, or partially (e.g thumbnail is not removed when cursor leaves the link). Can somebody help me to fix that function?

Comment: If you're using jQuery anyway, why are'nt you using a proper event handler ?

Comment: It is because you are registering the `hover` callback on the mouse over. so when the first mouse over happens the hover is registered with the tooltip and second time it is shown

Comment: @ArunPJohny I understand, but I need to call that function using `onmouseover`, if I remove that `.hover` method, my function start acting crazy..

Answer (score 0):

Try making the following changes

```
"<a " . $thumbs . " href=\"" . $url . "\" class=\"download\" rel=\"files/" . $dir . "/" . $file . "\" title=\"" . $alt . "\"   image=\"".$url_thumb."\" > </a>"
```

And

```
$(function() {
    var screenshot = $("<p id='screenshot'><img src='data:image/jpg;base64,"
            + data + "' alt='Atsisiusti' /></p>").hide()
            .appendTo('body');
    var img = $('img', screenshot);

    $('.download[image]').hover(function(e) {
            $.get($(this).attr('image'), function(data) {
                img.attr('src', 'data:image/jpg;base64,'
                                + data);
            });

            img.removeAttr('src');

            screenshot.css({
                'top' : (e.pageY - xOffset) + 'px',
                'left' : (e.pageX + yOffset) + 'px'
            }).fadeIn("fast");
        }, function() {
            screenshot.hide();
    }).mousemove(function(e) {
            screenshot.css({
                'top' : (e.pageY - xOffset) + 'px',
                'left' : (e.pageX + yOffset) + 'px'
            })
    });

})
```